# Active Directory authentication with Apache: why I need to use a full name (user at domain)?

Tags: apache-2.2, active-directory, authentication

We use Apache 2.2 for authentication against Active Directory.
The configuration is following:

```
AuthFormLDAPURL "ldap://*.*.*.*:389/DC=domain,DC=com?userPrincipalName,sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"
```

*Note: All traces below using WireShark.*

I defined the user john when the CN is equal to the sAMAcountMame name:

[image]

I can authenticate using only john (sAMAcountMame). Please find below LDAP bind request:

[image]

LDAP bind response:

[image]

Then I defined the user johnd when the CN is NOT equal to the sAMAcountMame name:

[image]

Unfortunately, I can not authenticate using johnd (sAMAcountMame). Please find below LDAP bind request:

[image]

LDAP bind response:

[image]

I can authenticate using a full name jonhd@domain.com. Please find below LDAP bind request:

[image]

LDAP bind response:

[image]

Questions:

1. Why I can not authenticate using sAMAcountMame when the CN is NOT equal to the sAMAcountMame?
2. Why I can authenticate using sAMAcountMame at domain in this case?
3. Should we recommend to our users always to authenticate using sAMAcountMame at domain to prevent the authentication problems?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please give more details about your `AuthLDAP*` configuration. There is something strange — because the user-specified name ends up in the bind request, looks like you are using something like `AuthLDAPInitialBindAsUser on`, but you also tell that you are using Apache 2.2, and there is no such option in that version (it was added in 2.3.6). Also `AuthFormLDAPURL` is either a typo or some custom module not known even to Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When performing LDAP simple bind, AD does not try to match the passed name against the `sAMAccountName` attribute without any suffixes. However, it could try to find a match against `displayName`, which worked for you in the first test (where it looked like a match against `sAMAccountName`, because values of those attributes were the same).

The precise description of name matching rules used when handling LDAP simple binds can be found in the Microsoft documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223499.aspx

Using UPN is probably more reliable, because `displayName` might contain some human-readable string (e.g., full name of a person) and is not guaranteed to be unique. The DOMAIN\USERNAME form should also be unique, but depend on NetBIOS domain names, which are considered to be obsolete now.

Comment: Thanks for you answer (+1). Can you guess why I can not to login using `DOMAIN\USERNAME` but can login using `USERNAME@DOMAIN`? The `DOMAIN\USERNAME` is unique.

Comment: Did you look at the bind request using Wireshark in this case, and is `DOMAIN\USERNAME` there? Note that `DOMAIN` must be the NetBIOS domain name, which is by default the same as the first component of the DNS domain name, but can also be set to something else when creating the domain.